# Amazon MTurk SDK Ruby gem - RuntimeError: Missing AWSAccessKey

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mechanicalturk

How/where does a rails app specify the MTurk Key & Secret?

The Amazon Mechanical Turk SDK gem docs do not seem to indicate where/how to specify the Access Key and Secret... if you run their sample code in IRB it prompts for the Key and Secret... but where does one specify them in a one-time configuration so an application can run?

For example Amazon gives this code:

```
require 'mturk'
@mturk = Amazon::WebServices::MechanicalTurkRequester.new
puts "I have $#{@mturk.availableFunds} in Sandbox"
```

which causes the gem to prompt interactively for the Key and Secret.

Doing this instead:

```
mturk = Amazon::WebServices::MechanicalTurkRequester.new :AWSAccessKeyId => "xxxx", :AWSSecretAccessKey => "yyyy
```

gives the error message:

```
RuntimeError: Missing AWSAccessKey
```

The key & secret being specified is definitely correct, because I can copy/paste them into the interactive prompt and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is documented anywhere I fail to find it, but the answer is that unlike every other AWS library I've used they rename the 'secret' to :AWSAccessKey

So this works:

```
mturk = Amazon::WebServices::MechanicalTurkRequester.new :AWSAccessKeyId => "xxxx", : AWSAccessKey => "yyyy
```